# Blurring an image using gaussian blur in c

Tags: c, gaussianblur

So I have seen a lot of people doing gaussian blur using other programming language so i am trying to do in C but it seems my code is not working.
So at first I have asked user input for the image file then its width and height. After inputting the file name its width and height it seems the output file is in binary so it comes as an unsupported file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
 
int main()
{
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    char path_in[64], path_out[64];
    unsigned char **rev, px;
    int sum, width, height, read, i, j;
     
    printf("Input file name: ");
    scanf("%s", path_in);
    printf("Output file name: ");
    scanf("%s", path_out);
     
    printf("Width of image (in pixels): ");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    printf("Height of image (in pixels): ");
    scanf("%d", &height);
     
    fin = fopen(path_in, "rb");
    fout = fopen(path_out, "wb");
     
    rev = (unsigned char **)malloc(height * sizeof(unsigned char *));
    for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
        rev[i] = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * sizeof(unsigned char));
    //Store pixel values from image in a width x height unsigned char matrix
    for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            read = fread(&px, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fin);
            rev[i][j] = px;
        }
    }
    //Blur image using average of neighboring pixels
    sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //Top row of image
            if(i == 0)
            {
                if(j == 0)
                    sum = (rev[i][j] + rev[i][j + 1] + 
                            rev[i + 1][j] + rev[i + 1][j + 1]) / 4;
                else if(j == width - 1)
                    sum = (rev[i][j] + rev[i][j - 1] +
                            rev[i + 1][j] + rev[i + 1][j - 1]) / 4;
                else
                    sum = (rev[i][j] + rev[i][j - 1] + rev[i][j + 1] +
                            rev[i + 1][j] + rev[i + 1][j - 1] + rev[i + 1][j + 1]) / 6;
            }
            //Bottom row of image
            else if(i == height - 1)
            {
                if(j == 0)
                    sum = (rev[i][j] + rev[i][j + 1] + 
                            rev[i - 1][j] + rev[i - 1][j + 1]) / 4;
                else if(j == width - 1)
                    sum = (rev[i][j] + rev[i][j - 1] +
                            rev[i - 1][j] + rev[i - 1][j - 1]) / 4;
                else
                    sum = (rev[i][j] + rev[i][j - 1] + rev[i][j + 1] +
                            rev[i - 1][j] + rev[i - 1][j - 1] + rev[i - 1][j + 1]) / 6;
            }
            //Left side of image (excluding top or bottom row)
            else if(j == 0)
                sum = (rev[i][j] + rev[i - 1][j] + rev[i + 1][j] +
                        rev[i][j + 1] + rev[i - 1][j + 1] + rev[i + 1][j + 1]) / 6;
            //Right side of image (excluding top or bottom row)
            else if(j == width - 1)
                sum = (rev[i][j] + rev[i - 1][j] + rev[i + 1][j] + 
                        rev[i][j - 1] + rev[i - 1][j - 1] + rev[i + 1][j - 1]) / 6;
            //Pixels not on a border of the image
            else
                sum = (rev[i][j] + rev[i][j - 1] + rev[i][j + 1] + rev[i - 1][j] + rev[i + 1][j] + 
                        rev[i - 1][j - 1] + rev[i - 1][j + 1] + rev[i + 1][j - 1] + rev[i + 1][j + 1]) / 9;
            rev[i][j] = (unsigned char)sum;
        }
    }
    //Write each pixel in rev to output file
    for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if(j < width && i < height)
                fwrite(&rev[i][j], sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fout);
        }
    }
    //Close input and output file
    fclose(fout);
    fclose(fin);
     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use some sort of C graphics (`graphics.h`?  I think that's standard) to print out the blurred image by `putpixel`ing each stored pixel?

Comment: "Blurring a bitmap image" is little more than averaging values in an array, using some function. In your case, one with a Gausian distribution. If the question is about blurring, you can see if it works on a simple 2d array. If the question is about reading and writing standard image formats, ask it and specify an operating system.